# How to set optional date? : Milliseconds to date

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm guessing this is happening because of different timezone.
when I call 2020-01-01, it returns 2019-12-31.

Any helps?
please, only vanilla JS.

```js
var automationStartDate = function(yy, mm, dd){
  let date = new Date(yy, mm, dd);

  var year = date.getFullYear(yy);
  var month = date.getMonth(mm);
  var day = date.getDay(dd);

  return date;
}

console.log(automationStartDate(2020,00,01));
// It returns 2019-12-31T15:00:00.000Z
// I suppose this should return 2020-01-01T15:00:00
```

Comment: The constructor assumes local values, but some consoles use *toISOString* when logging a date. If you're in a timezone that is UTC+9, then 2020-01-01 will be 2019-12-31T15:00:00Z (i.e. UTC). It's the same moment in time, just different offset. Just do `console.log(automationStartDate(2020,0,1).toString())` to get local values. BTW, using `00` and `01` is bad form, it appears like you're using octal (and is octal in some ancient browsers).

Comment: @JustDoo : your title, initial sentence and code snippet are out of sync (the snippet does not describe the sentence, the link with the title is not clear). Could you please rephrase your issue and question ?

Comment: @JustDoo : RobG's comment gives a very likely cause of why using `console.log(date)` could confuse you. Do you have some issues in other places of your code where you use dates ?

Answer (score -1):

`.setFullYear()` only sets the "yy, mm, dd" part of the date, not the "h, m, s".

You can use the `.setHours()` method, to set the "h, m, s" part.

---

My previous answer was :

Use the appropriate constructor :

```
let date = new Date(yy, mm, dd, h, m ,s);
```

<strike>but I forgot this contructor only understands UTC dates, and you need to manipulate a Date in your local timezone.</strike>

It should return the date you expect.

---

See references on MDN :

- [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Syntax)
- [setFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear)
- [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#Syntax)

Comment: when I run the function, automationStartDate(2020,0,1);, it gives 2019-12-31T15:00:00.000Z. How can I get 2020-01-01 not 2019-12-31?

Comment: What is your local timezone ? UTC-9 ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Does `.setHours(h, m, s)` suit your need ?

Comment: The OP isn't using *set* for anything, it can't be the issue. "*this contructor[sic] only understands UTC dates*" is wrong, it assumes local values.

Comment: @RobG : question was edited, see "edited" link for original question. You are right about the Date() constructor : the spec says it should create dates in local timezone, not in UTC.